# Angularjs display data in function

Tags: angularjs

I am taking NorthEast coordinates with the following code. But how can I show this lat0 coordinate in the marker function. Can you help me?

```js
google.maps.event.addListener($scope.map, 'idle', function(event){
   var lat0 = $scope.map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat();
   var lng0 = $scope.map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng();
   var lat1 = $scope.map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat();
   var lng1 = $scope.map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng();
   });
```

this is working well but how to show lat0 in marker funtion

```js
var createMarker = function (info) {
 
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: $scope.map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(info.lat, info.lng),
            title: info.prop_Name,
   animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
   lat0 : **lat0** ?? notworking ??
        });
  }
```

note: info.lat0 not working

Comment: What are you trying to make exactly? 'Cause a marker is defined by a lat and a lng and you have it in the marker object.

Comment: I want to show lat0 in the div. For example {{marker.lat0}}

Comment: my full code https://jsfiddle.net/vipul_me/Lsvqygff/6/

Comment: i want show lat0 in <div ng-app="hotelApp" ng-controller="ContentControler"> {{marker.lat0}} </div>

Comment: See my answer and this plkr: https://jsfiddle.net/x2nt8onf/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables are not updated with the digest cycle.

Use apply on your scope and it works great.

```
google.maps.event.addListener($scope.map, 'idle', function
    $scope.test = $scope.map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat();
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

Template:

```
Lat0: {{test}}
```

I just made tests, I let you use it as you want with your markers.

Comment: Hi, it will be a responsibility. You can write me the price of the search result page of airbnb site.

Comment: HI @MehmetGenç  what do you mean?

Comment: Could you write me the airbnb.com search result page? How much is the fee? https://www.airbnb.com.tr/s/Paris--France?page=1&s_tag=eH9-Pa63&allow_override%5B%5D= php+mysql+angular